# In $.ajax(), why is the request method option named 'type'?

Tags: jquery

In jQuery's [**$.ajax()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method, why is the option for specifying the HTTP-request method named `type` instead of `method`? Is there a reason for this, I mean does the option-name `type` signify anything more?

Note: I know the name of the option doesn't matter a bit. But would still like to know since I believe jQuery usually aligns itself very well to established conventions and vocabulary.

Comment: maybe ask the jq developers, guess they have the best answer to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it specifies the **type** of request `$.ajax` will make. Maybe its in an effort to differentiate from `method` because it supports `PUT` and `DELETE` on top of `GET` and `POST`.

From [`$.ajax` doco](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> type (default: 'GET')
>
> Type: String
>
> The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

Comment: I've seen that in the docs. but the thing is that *type of request* has a universally known term which is `HTTP-request-method`.

Comment: It's their standard, the only way to be 100% sure about a question like "why did someone name something like this" is to ask the people who named it.